# Is there such a formula in general topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I can prove the following formula in general topology:
$$
(A\cup B)^o\subset (A^o\cup \overline{B})\tag1
$$
This formula is useful in proving many results involving interiors (and closures) because it provides an upper bound for $(A\cup B)^o$. But after checking several books on general topology including *Topology* by Kuratowski and Munkres, and *General Topology* by Bourbaki, I can not find it.

So I wonder if this formula already exists or not. Also, I'd like to know if there is a handbook in general topology.

**Edit:** In his *Topology* ((15) on p56, Vol1), Kuratowski proved the following formula indirectly through local topology.
$$
\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A\cup B}}}\,=\,\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A}}}\cup\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{B}}}\tag2
$$
However, (2) can be proved easily by (1) as follows.
$$
\overset{\circ}{\overline{A\cup B}}\,=\left(\left(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\right)^o\right)^o\subset \left(\overset{\circ}{\overline{A}}\cup\overline{B}\right)^o\subset \overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A}}}\cup\overset{\circ}{\overline{B}}\,\subset \overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A}}}\cup\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{B}}}
$$
Since the right is closed
$$
\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A\cup B}}}\,\subset\,\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{A}}}\cup\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline{B}}}
$$
The other part is obvious. So I think Kuratowski might not know this and (1) may be new.

Comment: Sometimes you will find elementary formulas like this buried in an example or an exercise in a textbook; did you search through the examples and exercises of those books? But I'll say that there are way too many elementary formulas for the comparatively few textbooks around, so I would not be at all surprised if no-one had yet put this formula into a textbook.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know it is most likely In examples or exercises. But I can not find it in them. Do you know if there is a handbook in general topology?

Comment: Does $(A\cup B)^o$ mean the interior of $A\cup B$?

Comment: @KentaS yes it does.

Comment: Are you asking if this relation is true? Have you proved it?

Comment: Yes, I can prove it.

Comment: The inclusion gives us $i(kA\cup kB)\subset(ikA\cup kB)\subset kikA\cup kB$ where $k$ is closure and $i$ interior, from which $kik(A\cup B)\subset kikA\cup kikB$ follows immediately by symmetry. The other direction is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x\in(A\cup B)^\circ$ and $x\notin\overline B$. Thus, for some open subset $U\subset A\cup B$ we have $x\in U$, and for some open subset $V\subset B^c$ we have $x\in V$. Thus $x\in U\cap V=(A\cup B)\cap B^c\subset A$, so $x\in A^\circ$.

Comment: Maybe a simpler formulation is that $(A \cup B)^{\circ} - \overline{B}$ is an open set which contains $x$ and is contained in $A$.

Comment: or even just, $(A \cup B)^{\circ} - \overline{B}$ is an open set which is contained in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall seeing it before in the extensive literature on the Kuratowski closure-complement problem.

Since $k(iA\cup kB)=kiA\cup kB=k(iA\cup B)$ it implies the inclusion $ki(A\cup B)\subset k(iA\cup B)$ where $k$ is closure and $i$ interior.

There should be an index of elementary point-set topological results somewhere. Here are some I used recently [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10928) where $f$ is boundary, $g$ border $(gA=A\cap f\!A),$ and $c$ complement.

**1**  If $A$ and $iB$ are closed then $i(A\cup B)=iA\cup iB.$

**2**  If $A$ and $B$ each satisfy $kik=k$ then so does $A\cup B.$

**3**  $f(A\cap B)=(k(A\cap B)\setminus iA)\cup(k(A\cap B)\setminus iB).$

**4**  $ikA=ik(A\cap ikA)=ik(A\cap kikA).$

**5**  If $A\cup B$ satisfies $kik=ki$ then $i\!f\!A\subset ikB.$

**6**  If $i\!f\!A$ and $iB$ are both empty then $ki(A\cup B)=kiA.$

**7**  If $i\!f\!A$ is empty and $i\!f\!B$ is closed then $i\!f(A\cup gB)=i\!f(A\cup gcB).$

**8**  If $i\!f\!A$ is empty then $i\!f\!B\subset i\!f(A\mathop\triangle B)$ for all $B.$

**9**  If $kikB=kiB$ and $fikA=fik(A\cap B)=\emptyset,$ then
$fikB\subset\{fki(A\cup B)\cap fik(A\cup B)\}.$

**10**  If $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ each satisfy $iki=i$ and $kiB=kB,$ then $ikiA\setminus iA\subset fki(A\cap B).$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof (by algebra):
\begin{align*}
 \left(A\cup B\right)^{o}-A^{o}\cup\overline{B}\:&=\, \left(A\cup B\right)^{o}\cap\left(\left(A^{o}\right)^{c}\cap\left(B^{c}\right)^{o}\right)
 \\
 &=\, \left((A\cup B)\cap B^c\right)^{o}\cap\left(A^{o}\right)^{c}
 \\
 &=\, \left(A^{o}\cap\left(B^{c}\right)^{o}\right) \cap\left(A^{o}\right)^{c}
 \\
 &=\, \varnothing
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the standard identity that interior commutes with intersection:
$$(A\cup B)^\circ\smallsetminus\overline B=(A\cup B)^\circ\cap(X\smallsetminus B)^\circ=\bigl((A\cup B)\cap(X\smallsetminus B)\bigr)^\circ\subseteq A^\circ,$$
where $X$ is the ambient topological space.